# Não consigo ler o valor que vem do arduino para o Cordova

Tags: apache-cordova, bluetooth, cordova-plugin, phonegap-buillder

Bom dia,

Eu tenho uma aplicação em Cordova. Eu quero conectá-la ao arduino através do bluetooth. 
Não consigo receber o valor que vem do arduino

```
var macAddress = "00:06:66:4D:00:00";

var app = {
    initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function () {
        bluetoothSerial.connect(macAddress, app.onConnect, app.onDisconnect);
    },
    onConnect: function () {
        statusDiv.innerHTML = "Connected to " + macAddress + ".";
        bluetoothSerial.subscribe("\n", app.onMessage, app.subscribeFailed);
        bluetoothSerial.read(function (data) { console.log(data, 'read'); }, app.subscribeFailed);
    },
    onDisconnect: function () {
        alert("Disconnected");
        statusDiv.innerHTML = "Disconnected.";
    },
    onMessage: function (data) {
        console.log(data, 'onMessage');
        counter.innerHTML = data;
    },
    subscribeFailed: function () {
        alert("subscribe failed");
    }
};
```

A consola dá-me isto:

```
 The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported. (index):65 
 adding proxy for Battery (index):65 
 adding proxy for Camera (index):65 
 adding proxy for File (index):65 
 adding proxy for Capture (index):65 
 adding proxy for Device (index):65 
 adding proxy for Accelerometer (index):65 
 adding proxy for Compass (index):65 
 adding proxy for Globalization (index):65
 adding proxy for InAppBrowser (index):65 
 adding proxy for NetworkStatus (index):65 
 adding proxy for SplashScreen (index):65
 Persistent fs quota granted (index):65 
 Error: exec proxy not found for :: StatusBar :: _ready (index):65 
 bluetoothSerial.connect: 00:06:66:4D:00:00 (index):65 
 bluetoothSerial.subscribe ' ' (index):65
 bluetoothSerial.read:  (index):65  read
```

Eu penso que eu estou conectada com o bluetooth mas não consigo obter os dados que vem do arduino.
Na consola eu noteu esta linha:

```
Error: exec proxy not found for :: StatusBar :: _ready (index):65
```

Pode ser este o problema?
Se sim, como o posso resolver?
(estou a trabalhar em windows 10);

Obrigada.

Answer (score 0):

Tente rodar o seguinte comando:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git
```